# Write-Progress based on another cmdlet progress status

Tags: powershell, progress

I have a Powershell script using the [Get-QADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) cmdlet several times. This cmdlet is reporting progress with a progress bar.

So, let's consider this script,

```
$user = Get-QADUser "User1"
$user = Get-QADUser "User2"
$user = Get-QADUser "User3"
$user = Get-QADUser "User4"
```

If we consider that each statement represents 25% of my total script execution time (no need to be exact), I'd like to `Write-progress` based on these cmdlets' progress. In other words, this would represent a global progress bar for the script.

So, if `$user = Get-QADUser "User1"` is at 50% progress, I'd like to report ~13% (50% of 25%). My problem is, I don't if it's possible to have access to the `Get-QADUser` progress in live time.

Is their a way to call `Write-Progress -PercentComplete` based on a third party cmdlet in Powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users_added = @()
$users = @('User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4')

Write-Progress -Activity 'Create User' -ID 1 -PercentComplete 0

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $users.count; $i++ ) {
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Create User' -ID 1 -PercentComplete $($i / $users.count * 100)
    $users_added += Get-QADUser $users[$i]
}
```

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that `Get-QADUser $users[$i]` can return more than one user. In this case my progress won't be representative. This is why I wanna based my `Write-Progress` on the actual progress status of the cmdlet if possible.